# BIND and DNSSEC setup debugging

Tags: bind, dns-zone, dnssec

I am trying to get DNSSEC up and running, but I'm having some difficulties getting it working.

I am running BIND 9.14.2 (on Windows of all things). BIND is working fine and there's have a number of zones in production on these servers. I just cant seem to get my test zone signed for some reason. Unsure why.

Here's what I have done so far. I have created a new zone called test.com. For this I have generated a pair of keys:

The Key Signing Key:

```
dnssec-keygen -a RSASHA256 -f KSK -K "d:\zonekeys" test.com
```

And the Zone Signing Key:

```
dnssec-keygen -a RSASHA256 -K d:\zonekeys\ test.com
```

They both exist on disk and looks alright.

```
d:\zonekeys\Ktest.com.+008+44385.key
d:\zonekeys\Ktest.com.+008+44385.private
d:\zonekeys\Ktest.com.+008+47869.key
d:\zonekeys\Ktest.com.+008+47869.private
```

The zone is configured as such...

```
zone test.com {
    type master;
    file "test.com.zone";
    key-directory "d:\zonekeys";
    auto-dnssec maintain;
    inline-signing yes;
};
```

The zone is working and I can DIG it just fine. It just has no DNSSEC response.

The questions is why? I have ensured that eDNS is enabled. Zone has been updated. BIND restarted, rndc reload and all that. It just acts as if there's no DNSSEC at all.

A test.com.zone.signed file has been generated and exist as a binary file of sorts. I suspect that it is beeing served, but simply doesn't contain any signed data. Should it contain signed data? As I understand "inline-signing" means that it should sign the zone "on the fly" when served.

What am I missing here? Why am I not getting any DNSSEC signed response?

Comment: Did you look in the logs? If something goes wrong (e.g. Bind does not have permissions to read the keys) it signals it in the logs. Did you use `dig` with the `+dnssec` option?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @piotr-p-karwasz for pointing me in the right direction. It was indeed an accessrights issue to the .private files. In the named_debug.log i found the following

```
20-Dec-2019 9:42:03.665 general: warning: dns_dnssec_findmatchingkeys: error reading key file Ktest.com.+008+44385.private: permission denied
20-Dec-2019 9:42:03.665 general: warning: dns_dnssec_findmatchingkeys: error reading key file Ktest.com.+008+47869.private: permission denied
```

It turned out that inheritance was disabled for the folder where i had my key files (d:\zonekeys), so the bind process had no access to these files, only to the folder.